# Are the Tesla values of an MRI only related to the external static magnetic field?

Tags: mri, radiology

Does a *3T MRI* have 3 Tesla as magnetic field strength related to the external superconducting constant magnetic field or does it also include the maximum magnetic field strength at the position where the gradient is highest from the field of the gradient coils during scanning?

From [here](https://cdn0.scrvt.com/39b415fb07de4d9656c7b516d8e2d907/1800000003935737/86b3e50bba10/gradient-performance-and-gradient-amplifier-power_blasche_v2_1800000003935737.pdf) I've found the following:

> The highest peak amplitude in a commercially available
> whole-body 3-Tesla MR system is 80 mT/m. This means that
> the magnetic field at full gradient strength varies over the
> maximum field of view of 50 cm (± 25cm) by ± 0.02T.

Then why is it called a *"3T MRI"* rather than a *"3,02T MRI"*?

Or is this simply disregarded because the relative difference is far too small?

Comment: You answered the question. It's a classification, not a specification. Would you expect that if a company developed a 3.025T or 3.018T MRI for it to be called something other than a 3T?

Answer (score 1):

An MRI scanner involves three magnetic fields:

[B0](https://radiopaedia.org/articles/b0-1?lang=gb), the main magnetic field produced by the scanner, which is relatively static.

[Gradient field](https://mriquestions.com/gradient-coils.html), produced by the gradient coils to tune 'slices' of the object being imaged to the appropriate frequency.

[Shim coils](https://mriquestions.com/why-shimming.html), used to even out irregularities of the B0 field.

(There is also the electromagnetic field associated with the radiofrequency pulse sequence, which is much smaller in magnitude again).

The classification of the scanner is based on the nominal strength of the B0 field that it produces. There will be variations between individual scanners, and the peak field strength during a scan will vary slightly as you describe in the question, but by a small fraction of the average field strength.